# PHP code doesnt work together with JS function on "onclick"

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

i have a button in which i want it to perform 2 task; php and js.
The php part : generate different text everytime the button is pressed.
The js part : disabling the button for 5 secs and then enabling it back.

**HTML**

```
 <button onclick = "disable();"  class=btnGenerate type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" >GENERATE</button>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$num=mt_rand(1,10);
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from quote_table where id=$num");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();}
```

**JS**

```
 <script>
function disable(){
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() { enable(); }, 5000);    }

function enable(){
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
}</script>
```

The PHP part only works when i delete the *"onclick = "disable();"* on the html but it doest seem to work when i add it. Can a button carry out PHP and JS at a single click ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: just remove `type="submit"`  and run the code

Comment: @SantoshSuryawanshi — That shouldn't make any difference whatsoever. `type="submit"` is the default and nothing is explicitly testing for the attribute.

Comment: @SantoshSuryawanshi didnt work.

Comment: I don't understand your intent with this code.  If you are submitting a form: 1. disabled inputs won't  be added to the form data passed to the server and 2. the page will reload, rendering the enable() function pointless. You also should be using `addEventListener()` to handle events on a form element rather than putting javascript inline.

Comment: my intent on using the button is for, when the user pressed the button, the php code will execute and get text from the database to be displayed on the page,, at the same time after each click, the button will be disable for 5 seconds by the js ,, @JonathanEltgroth

Comment: Are you expecting the page to reload, or the data to simply return so you can re-enable the submit button?

Comment: data to simply return ,, just for the php to run again to generate new  different text from the database. @JonathanEltgroth

Comment: Yeah, you need to use an Ajax call then.  Once you trigger a form submit the browser will fetch the data from the server based on the forms action url, but your page's javascript is at that point no longer relevant, because the browser is going to reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

A disabled button can't be a successful control.

Don't depend on the name/value of the submit button being submitted in the form data if you are going to disable it.

Replace `isset($_POST['submit'])` with some other condition.

Comment: so what can i use as another condition, so that when the button is pressed the php code will execute along with the js.

Comment: You could test if it was a POST request and not a GET request. You could test if some other data in the form was present. You could just have the code to generate the form and the code to process the form submission in different PHP programs. The list goes on.

Comment: @DanialWafiy, I think you're misunderstanding how PHP and JS work. PHP and JS do not work with each other.  They're separate code that run in separate environments, PHP on the server, JS in the browser.  They cannot run simultaneously.

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth — It's a submit button. Clicking it submits a form. That triggers an HTTP request. That causes the server to run some PHP.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but it seems he's asking why the javascript isn't working in-conjunction with the PHP, like he wants to submit the form and still have the js on the page function, even though he's not using an ajax request.  It's not possible.  Once the form is submitted, the javascript is no longer valid because the browser is about to accept a new request and regenerate a fresh page.

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth — onclick events run before form submission. The point of disabling a submit button when it is clicked is usually to guard against *duplicate* submissions, so it doesn't matter if it doesn't also run on the subsequent page.

Answer (score 0):

If you trigger a form submission, unless you're using AJAX the page will simply reload, rendering the `enable()` method moot unless
    you're using it to re-enable the button on fail condition or on
    successful return of data via AJAX.

It's sounds to me like you're trying to get data via request to the server, without reloading the page, and then re-enable the submit button after the data is returned.  In that case you need to use AJAX.

**HTML**

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="form">
  <button class=btnGenerate type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" >GENERATE</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // prevents browser from submitting form
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
  // using JQuery ajax
  $.ajax(form.action, {
    data: form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() { // runs before ajax call made
      // disable submit button
      submit.disabled = true;
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      // deal your return data here
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      // deal with error
    },
    complete: function() { // runs when ajax call fully complete
      // renable submit button
      submit.disabled = false;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```